# Can't figure out the Terraform configuration equivalent for creating address for VPC Peering and networking service for GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'd like to access my CloudSQL instance from my GKE Cluster pods. Since I am setting up I need to bring everything GCP related to the Terraform configuration files.

Following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-kubernetes-engine#gcloud_2

I am stuck with two steps that describe the creating of a peering vpc connection.

So my question is what are the Terraform equivalents for the following two commands:

```sh
gcloud compute addresses create google-managed-services-default \
--global \
--purpose=VPC_PEERING \
--prefix-length=16 \
--description="peering range for Google" \
--network=default
```

and

```sh
gcloud services vpc-peerings connect \
--service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com \
--ranges=google-managed-services-default \
--network=default
```

I tried to find it in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs but could not find the proper ones.

Answer (score 5):

Creating the address would be like this:

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "address_resource" {
  provider      = google-beta # from docs
  name          = "google-managed-services-default"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  prefix_length = "16"
  network       = google_compute_network.network_resource.id
  address       = "REPLACE_WITH_VALUE" # or remove it to automatically select an unused address range in your VPC network
}
```

and the service connection would be like this:

```
resource "google_service_networking_connection" "foobar" {
  network                 = google_compute_network.network_resource.id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.address_resource.name]
}
```

links:

- [Example Usage - Global Address Private Services Connect](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_global_address#example-usage---global-address-private-services-connect)
- [Google Service Networking Connection](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/service_networking_connection)

Comment: Wait a moment I just added the 'google-beta' part. However now my terraform service account is having troubles with permissions for `compute.globalAddresses.get`. I guess that is another problem. Will be back with an update if I got around that

Comment: Try without it, maybe the documentation is not updated yet!

Comment: Nope it did not work either. I still end up with this issue here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/11100